# DVR is PID proof

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

I already know that if $R$ is a Noetherian local ring with Krull dimension $1$, then $R$ is DVR if and only if its maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}$ is principal ideal if and only if every nonzero ideal is a power of $\mathfrak{m}$.

From those facts, I think I can say that $R$ is PID. Is this true?

Comment: Compare with the equivalent statements [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2198198/equivalent-characterizations-of-discrete-valuation-rings). The proofs are just a few lines. So you only need $(1)\Rightarrow (2)$ to see that a DVR is Euclidean and hence a PID.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Thank you for your comment. But I think the statement also followed by what I wrote in the post. I wonder if my thought is correct

Comment: Yes, your thought is $(10)$ implying $(3)$ in the duplicate. This is also correct.

Comment: It is obvious that in a DVR with $\pi$ of minimal non-zero valuation then the non-zero ideals are exactly the $(\pi^n)$